# cakephp habtm nested data

Tags: cakephp

I have a HABTM relationship and I'd like to get nested data for a categories table from a product table something like this product array:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'name' => 'a',
        'categories' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => (int) 1
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => (int) 2
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => (int) 2,
        'name' => 'b',
        'categories' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => (int) 1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Is this possible with cake?

EDIT: I will try to explain further what I want to do.

Please bear with me, I am new to cake and am having trouble getting to grips it.

I have a 'product' table:

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'joinTable' => 'categories_sculptures',
            'foreignKey' => 'sculpture_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting'
        )
    )
```

and a category table:

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Sculpture' => array(
            'className' => 'Sculpture',
            'joinTable' => 'categories_sculptures',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'sculpture_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting'
        )
    );
```

and a category products table:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Sculpture' => array(
        'className' => 'Sculpture',
        'foreignKey' => 'sculpture_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

I would like to build a view table of the sculptures and also show in each row which categories each sculpture is in (which could be more than one). As I am new to cake I don't know how I would go about this. If I was just querying mysql I could get this information with a group_concat or a nested select, or inefficiently by looping through first array and querying the category_sculpture table by sculpture key and adding the results to the first array. But I would like to know the best way to get this result the cake way.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my needs:

```
$this->Sculpture->recursive = 1;
```